# I would like to render the same page if new user is not save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to render on the same page if email is blank. However, when I leave in blank instead of staying on users/new. It goes to /users. It is still render to _from for the URL is different.

```
     def new
    respond_with(user)
  end

  def create
    if user.save
      user.send_invitation
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Signed up!"
    else
      render "/users/new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user.destroy
        redirect_to root_url, notice: "User was deleted successfully!"
    end
  end

  def edit
    respond_with(user)
  end

  def update
    params[:user].delete(:password) if params[:user][:password].blank?
    params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation) if params[:user][:password_confirmation].blank?
    if user.save
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "Saved your updates!"
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

Comment: what about `render :action => :new` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
render "/users/new"
```

Just renders template users/new, at create action. So the URL stays /users.

You can try to

```
  def create
    if user.save
      user.send_invitation
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Signed up!"
    else
      redirect_to new_user_path
    end
  end
```

But then you will have no access to submitted params, so the form will be clear.

Comment: Thanks, we are almost there. Now it is redirect_to the /users/new. The problem is when when the user.save is successfully saved is should go to /users. page

Comment: Then change root_url to users_path in create action of controller

Answer (score 0):

The thing in here I think it's a routes problem, as you want to persist the URL.

What Rails does in this cases is it goes to the create action once the form was submitted and if for some reason the record is not being save(in this case) you are rendering the new action but with the object which has errors and data.

To clean up a little bit you could do something like:

```
def create
 if user.save
   user.send_invitation
   redirect_to root_url, notice: "Signed up!"
 else
   render :new
 end
end
```

In my opinion, don't try to bend Rails this way, you'll get a lot of problems with it and also, does it really matters to persist the URL?

Redirection is not an option, because you'll loose all the data from the request, as it would become a new request due to the redirect.

Hope this helped!